# dx.chartjs: Global configuration

Tags: chart.js

I know how to specify chart configuration on a "per-chart" basis, for example this works fine:

```
$('#someDiv').dxChart({
    title: {
        text: 'Some title',
        font: {
            size: '1.25em'
        }
    },
dataSource: [...]
```

But I want to specify certain configuration settings (ie. color palette, title font-size, tool tip settings, ... ) for all charts in my application at once, instead of repeatedly specifying it on every chart. Is this possible?

I'm thinking about using `jQuery.merge` in some way to re-use a common configuration object, but I'm not really happy with this solution. Surely there must be a better way to achieve global configuration in dx.chartjs?